# Generate Scripts to move a database from one server to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to move a database from our testing server to my local server. I don't have the option of back up and restore since I don't have permission. So I decided to use the generate script option to create all the scripts for the DB and then move over the database to my local server. The problem I'm facing is that most of these tables have foreign key relationships and when I generate the scripts, they are being generated in alphabetical order and therefore my scripts are failing. Is there a way to generate scripts where the tables are aligned based on their foreign key relationships? If not, is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered applying the foreign keys separately, in a second pass?

Comment: I did not see the option to create tables without foreign keys in the Generate Scripts wizard. Am I missing something?

Comment: you are better off finding a SQL script to generate your objects - there are many examples on Google. THe best approach would be a tool that does this for you, I use Redgate SQLCompare and it would do this for you flawlessly.

Comment: I'm surprised SSMS isn't generating things in dependency order already, but... in Tools > Options > Scripting Options > Table/View Options > Script Foreign Keys = true/false. You'll have to create a second script with just the Foreign Keys, which could be a manual affair.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! I'll try out your suggestions.

Comment: The easy solution is to export the database as a [Data Tier Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15) dacpac and apply that to the target database. A `dacpac` is roughly a package of all the necessary scripts *but* it can be tracked, versioned and the server can check for changes. It's also possible to generate DIFF scripts between a database and dacpac, even from command-line tools, allowing you to easily publish modifications

Comment: When you create a Database Project in Visual Studio/SSDT the output is such a dacpac. You can publish that directly to another database if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change some settings on advanced options. Remember setting the right compatibility level of your target server, this option can mess up your script.

I've used this tool to migrate many times from SQL Server 2019 to 2019 (Windows and Linux) and to 2012.

One thing you have to check before saving your script is the encoding when you have to include data.

[image: advanced scripting options]

[image: compatibility level]

[image: encoding]